# How to Create Buffer in-order to avoid duplication of IN and OUT attendance

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make an IN and OUT, and Have done the whole program with it's database... Now the last is how do I make a time buffer inorder not to get a duplicate record with the same time.

this is the code that I have done to create the running code... Question is How do I make the buffer. I have search through the internet yet I couldn't find the suitable method

```
            ConnectToDB()
        sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.student_details_dub where f9  = '" & idnum & "'"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read

            TextBox2.Text = (dr("f2"))
            TextBox3.Text = (dr("f9"))
            TextBox4.Text = (dr("f4"))
            TextBox5.Text = (dr("f14"))
            TextBox6.Text = (dr("f3"))
            TextBox7.Clear()
            status.Text = "IN"

        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

        'ANOTHER FETCH
        ConnectToDB()
        sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring where id_num  = '" & idnum & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read

      
            If (dr("entry_record")) = "IN" Then
                record = "OUT"
            ElseIf (dr("entry_record")) = "OUT" Then
                record = "IN"
            ElseIf (dr("entry_record")) = String.Empty Then
                record = "IN"
            End If
            status.Text = (record)



        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()


        ConnectToDB()
        sql = "insert into monitoring (id_num, fname, lname, status, entry_record, floor_level, date) VALUES (@num, @name, @lname, @stat, @record, @lev,@date)"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)


        With cmd

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", idnum)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", TextBox6.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", TextBox5.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lev", levellock.sharevalue)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@record", status.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Date.Now)

            .ExecuteReader()
        End With



        MsgBox("Details has been saved!", vbInformation, "Saved")


        cmd = Nothing
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this what you meant because your english is horrible.

How about in the `Date.Now` you also include second so it become like this
`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

```
y = Year  
M = Month  
d = Date  

H = Hour  
m = Minute  
s = Second
```

Comment: 2022-11-28 16:49:08 its the same in my db sir